# User Verifier demo shows "waiting for kaa response..."

Tags: kaa

I am trying to run the UserVerification demo on kaa-0.9.0 Sandbox with android APK as client.

I register an facebook application and successfully configured the facebook user verifier on server. and then I succeed to run APK on emulator and then also login facebook. but it keeps showing **"Waiting for Kaa response..."** and I can't send message.

I was wondering if there is other anything I have to do with the server side? or I have to connect with multiple clients with the same user then I can have interactions?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: It worksnow after a sleeping,but I did restart my kaa server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you had some problems with internet connection, that's why your application was waiting for the response.

> I was wondering if there is other anything I have to do with the server side?

No, you shouldn't configure anything on the server side for this demo.

> I have to connect with multiple clients with the same user then I can have interactions?

Yes, if you want to see an interaction between two endpoints, you should install this app on different devices and log in with the same account. Otherwise, you will just send messages on one without seeing them on other.